# Approximately how long is the 'Massive' from Invader Zim?

Tags: spaceship, invader-zim

While watching the show *Invader Zim* on Hulu, I thought of something. Exactly how long is the *Massive*? I was wondering this because the exact length is never expressed, or even mentioned as being anything, in the show.

Comment: "*This depiction of the Massive seems to measure about half of Earth's diameter, according to a shot where the flagship is adjacent to the planet entering the Florpus Hole, which would make it about 6,000 km long.* - https://zim.fandom.com/wiki/Massive

Comment: I've not watched the show and I've no idea whether this information is accurate or not (which is why I posted it as a comment). If you are happy with it, and it seems to be correct, you might want to post it as a self answer.

Comment: i will settle for anything really. 6,000 kilometers is the best estimate given by the Invader Zim wiki

Comment: Your bounty reason is _"reward an existing answer."_ but the only answer is yours. Unless something drastic has changed you can't award a bounty to yourself.

Comment: oh, I was hoping that someone else had answered. If you want a chance at 100 reputation, this is your chance.

Comment: You can use "draw attention", "improve details", etc. to get other answers. The bounty reasons aren't _too_ important but saying reward an answer may put others off from answering.

Comment: sorry, I thought it meant to reward an answer when I thought one was good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About 6,000 Kilometers**
Judging by a shot from Invader Zim:Enter the Florpus, the Massive is about 6,000 km in length.

Comment: A screenshot would go nicely. Also, what object are they comparing it to. Don't forget that comments are ephemeral and could disappear at any time.

Comment: they are comparing it to the Earth. I have seen the movie at least three times. I know the part they are referring to.

Comment: @user14111 - OP is of course also OP. But you're not wrong about the answer needing some context

Comment: You should note that the ship in Enter the Florpus is the *[Super Massive](https://images.squarespace-cdn.com/content/v1/58bdb4b49f7456dff81be981/1572027215400-8E5TCHY9IRMTBUCUIQIB/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kLPswmMOqQZ9-Q6KHLjvbpZ7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QPOohDIaIeljMHgDF5CVlOqpeNLcJ80NK65_fV7S1UTcpTqfU-ZEsztPyQLxhSSK-PhJjRDDFQG0l3_ZnmWi1QjT9byXZM3ISxo3y1NRptg/023.jpg?format=750w)*, not the Massive. It's larger in every dimension. https://www.mrjakeparker.com/blog/2019/10/25/invader-zim